# Redirect certain subfolders by removing the parameter question mark

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using `.htaccess` to redirect certain subfolders of my domain, to remove the question mark to improve my URLs.

Currently my URLs are like this:

```
www.example.com/post/?sometitle
```

I am trying to remove the question mark, so it is the following URL:

```
www.example.com/post/sometitle
```

Currently I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /post/?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: "certain subfolders" - just a few specific folders? And by "folders", do you mean filesystem "directories" or URL "path segments"? Presumably you have already changed your application to use URLs of the form `/post/sometitle`? How are you then routing the URL?

Comment: i am using php GET parameters, i am attempting for when the browser visits 'https://www.example.com/post/sometitle' that the page that is currently 'https://www.example.com/post/?sometitle' is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am using php GET parameters, i am attempting for when the browser visits `example.com/post/sometitle` that the page that is currently `example.com/post/?sometitle` is displayed

In that case you need to the opposite of what you are asking in your question: you need to *internally rewrite* (not *externally* "redirect") the request from `example.com/post/sometitle` to `example.com/post/?sometitle`.

However, you must have already changed all the URLs in your application to use the new URL format (without the query string). You shouldn't be using `.htaccess` alone for this.

I also assume that `/post` is a physical directory and that you are really serving `index.php` in that directory (mod_dir is issuing an internal subrequest to this file). So, instead of `/post/?sometitle`, it's really `/post/index.php?sometitle`?

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /post/sometitle to filesystem path
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)$ /post/index.php?$1 [L]
```

So, now when you request `/post/sometitle` the request is internally rewritten and handled by `/post/index.php?sometitle` instead.

I have assumed that "sometitle" can consist of 1 or more of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`. Hence the regex `[\w-]+`.

If this is a new site then you can stop there. However, if you are changing an existing URL structure that has already been indexed by search engines and linked to by external third parties then you'll need to *redirect* the old URLs to the new. (Just to reiterate, you must have already changed the URL in your application, otherwise users will experience repeated redirects as they navigate your site.)

To implement the redirect, you can add something like the following *before* the above rewrite:

```
# Redirect any "stray" requests to the old URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^post/$ /post/%1 [R=302,NE,QSD,L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure we only redirect "direct requests" and thus avoiding a redirect loop.

(Change to 301 only when tested as OK, to avoid caching issues.)

**In Summary:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any "stray" requests to the old URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^post/$ /post/%1 [R=302,NE,QSD,L]

# Rewrite /post/sometitle to filesystem path
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)$ /post/index.php?$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** If you have multiple URLs ("folders") that all follow the same pattern, such as `/post/<title>`, `/home/<title>` and `/build/<title>` then you can modify the above to cater for all three, for example:

```
# Redirect any "stray" requests to the old URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^(post|home|build)/$ /$1/%1 [R=302,NE,QSD,L]

# Rewrite /post/sometitle to filesystem path
RewriteRule ^(post|home|build)/([\w-]+)$ /$1/index.php?$2 [L]
```

---

*Aside:* (With my [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) hat on...) This is not really much of an "improvement" to the URL structure. If this is an established website with many backlinks and good SE ranking then you should think twice about making this change as you could see a dip in rankings at least initially.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle multiple "subfolders".

Comment: Thank you Mr White, but i can not get it to work. Using 'RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+) /post/index.php?$1 [L]' I get a 500 Internal Server Error. If I change the URL to include the full site URL, like so 'RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+) https://www.example.com/post/index.php?$1 [L]' it redirects the browser to 'https://www.example.com/post/index.php?index' ??

Comment: Are OK, I've updated the regex to include a trailing `$` - this should prevent a rewrite loop (the probable cause of the 500 error). If you include an absolute URL in the _substitution_ it will indeed redirect - but that isn't what you want to do (although it can be useful in testing).

Comment: i am now using 'RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)$ /post/index.php?$1 [L]' but this redirects the browser to the home page (https://www.example.com)

Comment: That shouldn't "redirect" anything (it's an internal rewrite, not a redirect). Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. What URL are you requesting? Add your updated `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Mr White, got it working and accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

If only changing from query is your requirement then try with below, we are using [QSD](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag to discard our query string after our rule matched.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1 [R=302,L,NE,QSD]
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, but this is not working as desired, as it redirects every URL containing '/?' to 'www.mydomain.com'. I am attempting to have the browser goto 'www.mydomain.com/post/someothertitle' but display the page code at 'www.mydomain.com/post/?someothertitle'